Polars list nested-eval, how can I achieve something like Spark's transform
Lets say I have a column named structures which is a list of structs containing "a" and "b" inside of each. I want to avoid using explodes and such as my data structure is quite complex (and quite big), I want to work as much as possible with the lists alone.

    # Create a list of lists of structures
    list_of_structs = [
        [{"a":1, "b": 2}, {"a":3, "b": 4}, {"a":5, "b": 4}]
    ]

    # Create a DataFrame from the list of lists
    df = pl.DataFrame({"structures": list_of_structs})

My expected result would be a list of lists grouped by B
    [[(a1, b2)], [[(a3,b4)], (a5, b4)]] 

I want to perform some kind of "group all elements by B" (and then agg using concat_list), in spark the code (see how I reference X and Y) looks like this:

    arrays_grouped = F.array_distinct(
            F.transform(
                F.col("structures"),
                lambda x: (
                    F.filter(F.col("structures"),
                        lambda y: x.field("b") == y.field("b")
                    )
                ),
            )
        )

However in polars I can only see eval operator. https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html#polars.Expr.list.eval.
However I can't reference anything apart from pl.element() from outside the eval, so I'm quite stuck.
Do I need to implement this in plugins or there's a way with the provided API? This is my existing approach which does not work (probably influenced because I have been working quite long time with Spark functions).
    df = df.with_columns(
            #Gets all unique "b"
            pl.col("structures").list.eval(
                pl.element().struct.field("b")
            #Tries to filter structures all unique "b"
            ).list.unique().list.eval(
                pl.struct(
                    base:= pl.element(), 
                    df.get_column("structures").list.eval(
                        #Idk what this base value is, but its not filtering, if I replace it by hardcoded-4 it does filter 4s correctly
                        pl.element().filter(pl.element().struct.field("b") == base)
                    )
                )
            )
    )

I think something might be doable with gather, but I'm struggling to even start using it, as I can't find the indices to gather (similar issue to eval)

could you give an example of the result you'd like to get?
also, why exactly do you want to avoid explode()?

Added the expected result to the question thanks

I want to avoid explode because I want to avoid people exploding the whole dataframe and then grouping by (spark-style) as that wont work in my real datamodel which is heavily nested. If it can be done using series explode I think it will be fine (couldn't find a way either).  Basically what I'm trying to do is some kind of "list/series-level" groupBy (to use in deeply nested structures). Without the "agg" part (that will be my next task)

list_of_structs = [
    [{"a":1, "b": 2}, {"a":3, "b": 4}, {"a":5, "b": 4}],
    [{"a":2, "b": 5}, {"a":3, "b": 5}, {"a":4, "b": 3}]
]
        
df = pl.DataFrame({"structures": list_of_structs})

(df.select("structures")
   .with_row_index()
   .explode("structures")
   .unnest("structures")
   .group_by("index", "b", maintain_order=True) 
   .agg(
      pl.struct("a", "b")
   )
   .drop("b")
   .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
   .all()
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ index ┆ a                         │
│ ---   ┆ ---                       │
│ u32   ┆ list[list[struct[2]]]     │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ [[{1,2}], [{3,4}, {5,4}]] │
│ 1     ┆ [[{2,5}, {3,5}], [{4,3}]] │
└───────┴───────────────────────────┘

Performance
If I increase the row size as an example
df_big = df.sample(100_000, with_replacement=True)

And repeat the above approach:

Elapsed time: 0.45117 seconds

For comparison, if we perform the first list.eval step in your example:
df_big.with_columns(unique =
   pl.col("structures").list.eval(pl.element().struct["b"])
     .list.unique()
)


Elapsed time: 1.99926 seconds

Incidentally, it seems list.unique() is the major slowdown here, which can be avoided:
df_big.with_columns(unique =
   pl.col("structures").list.eval(pl.element().struct["b"].unique())
)


Elapsed time: 0.23198 seconds

Which is an improvement on the list.unique() version, but even then it is just a single piece of the functionality.
Adding further steps would likely end up much slower than the explode/group_by approach.

I don't have spark installed so I'm guessing your result, but maybe you can get the idea.
I'd say easy way of doing it would be DataFrame.explode() the list first, then DataFrame.unnest() the structure into columns a and b and then DataFrame.group_by and GroupBy.agg() into result:
(
    df
    .explode('structures')
    .unnest('structures')
    .group_by('b')
    .agg(pl.col('a').unique())
)

┌─────┬───────────┐
│ b   ┆ a         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 4   ┆ [3, 5]    │
│ 2   ┆ [1]       │
└─────┴───────────┘


Thanks for the answer, I realized this way after answering to you, however (with the multi-row dataframe as @jqurious proposed) in a DF with 10k rows and 5 list-elements per row. It perform a groupby of 50k rows, while the original was "simpler in terms of data movement/performance" (IMO), as it only required a groupby of 5 elements to be performed 10k times. In polars probably its not so bad, but for spark this would be something to avoid. Thats why I was looking for the "polars-equivalent" (i.e. doing it per-list in each row)

Ok, after thinking to answer @Roman Pekar, I made it work partially, this is how it looks (i still need to add with_row_index("rid"), as jqurious suggested)

   #Missing with_row_index
    df = df.withColumn(
     df.get_column("structures").list.explode().struct.unnest().group_by("b").agg(
            pl.struct(pl.col("a"),pl.col("b"))
        ).to_struct("structures")
    )


my mistake is that I was trying to work at "expr" level (so no dataframe was needed, lets say our library in spark only returns expressions) which is similar to what we do nowadays with Spark.
However this is sub-optimal IMO (not as bad as in Spark), as its doing a group_by of million of rows which should be worse (at least in parallelism) than doing it per-row. This is why I wanted to avoid explode (I was trying to avoid this answer :) )

It's the same as df.select("structures").explode("structures").unnest("structures").group_by("b").agg(pl.struct("a", "b")).to_struct() but you're losing the list here. If you use a 2-row dataframe example, you will also see the .agg() is not "row based" - you would need to use .with_row_index() before exploding. .group_by would also need a maintain_order=True to not lose original row order.

Apart from the row index part which you are right. For the real scenario it would be a with column, I just want to perform changes to the column without touching the original data.

also thats why I wanted to avoid the explode, in polars it might not be that much of an issue, but still not the most optimal. I only wanted to do a simple groupby of each row between 3 elements. With the explode it becomes a groupby of potentially millions of values (lets say I have 10m rows with a 3-sized lists in each row)

I think in the case of Polars, the opposite is true - the explode / group_by is the simpler case for it to parallelize. I've added some more info as an answer (too large for a comment).

Coming back to my question after a few weeks playing with polars and hitting it in my real problem.
the solution, while waiting for list.eval to be more powerful.
Exploding the whole dataframe is bad for my performance (my dataframe has maaaany columns) and memory.
The key here is to be aware that you can "for-free" add a Series to a DataFrame if it has the same length (which you guarantee with row count)

# This is "pseudocode", might not be fully 100% syntax correct

#column = column of type List(Struct(...))
row_index = "__tmp_rowindex"
exploded_df = df.select(column).with_row_count(row_index).explode(column)
exploded_df = exploded_df.with_columns(
    pl.col(column).struct.with_fields(pl.lit("Example").alias("blabla")
)

exploded_df = (
    exploded_df.group_by(row_index, maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col(column).alias(column)
    ).select(pl.col(column).list.drop_nulls().alias(column))
)
df = pl.concat([df.drop(column), exploded_df], how="horizontal")]).alias(column)
)


It looks like a horizontal concat e.g. pl.concat(..., how="horizontal") (which also works on LazyFrames)

ur right thanks!, updated the example
